# how can i show text depending on user id?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, registration

I am looking for a way to present a small text on the top of my wordpress website.
i want the text to be simple.
if the user is not logged in it will show " please login or register "
if the user is logged in it will show " welcome (username) , not you? "

can some one please help me out with this? 
i searched the web and found a few codes that dont seem to work like this one

```
<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['wordpressuser_' . COOKIEHASH])) {
$l = "";
global $user_identity, $user_ID, $user_level;
get_currentuserinfo();
switch ($user_level) {
case 0:
$l = 'Subscriber';
break;
case 1:
$l = 'Contributor';
break;
case 2:
$l = 'Author';
break;
case 3:
$l = 'Author Level 2';
break;
case 7:
$l = 'Editor';
break;
case 10:
$l = 'Administrator';
} ?>
<li><?php echo ($l); ?></li>
<li><?php echo('Name: ' . $user_identity); ?></li>
<li><?php echo('Articles posted: ' . get_usernumposts($user_ID)); ?></li>
<?php } else { ?>
<li>Not logged in/Non-member</li>
<li>Please <a href="<?php get_settings('siteurl') ?>/wp-login.php?action=login" title="Login">Login</a> or <a href="<?php get_settings('siteurl') ?>/wp-register.php" title="Become a member so you can write articles">Register</a>.</li>
<?php }
```

Answer (score 4):

From Wordpress Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
}
?>
```